# Bootstrap tooltip lag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am running into this issue where my bootstrap tooltips lag when I hover off them. There is about 1-2 seconds after I leave the image before the tooltip leaves. Has anyone else run into this? I am using react-bootstrap package with Meteor and here is a video of what I mean
http://imgur.com/oOuQLae

This is the code that I used, am I doing something wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export const Lecture = ({ tooltipDirection, lecture }) => {
  const tooltip = (
    <Tooltip key={"tooltip"+lecture._id} id={lecture.description} >{lecture.description}</Tooltip>
  );

  return(
    <Link to="/">
      <OverlayTrigger placement={tooltipDirection} overlay={tooltip} key={"overlayTrigger"+lecture._id}>
        <img src={lecture.image} className='img-responsive lectureListImage'  />
      </OverlayTrigger>
    </Link>
  )
};
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code. Although I have not used react router with tooltips. Maybe try extracting that to the parent component as a test.

Comment: did u found a solution for this?